# Prove that for each $\epsilon>0$, there exist a compact $K\subset E$ such that $m(E\cap K^c)<\epsilon$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, compactness

Let $E\subset\mathbb R$ be Lebesgue measurable with $m(E)<\infty$. Prove that for each $\epsilon>0$, there exist a compact $K\subset E$ such that $m(E\cap K^c)<\epsilon.$

Attempt

By contradiction, suppose that for all compact $K\subset E$, $m(E\cap K^c)\ge\epsilon.$

Notice that $K$ is Lebesgue measurable, thus $m(E)=m(E\cap K)+m(E\cap K^c)\ge(E\cap K)+\epsilon$

But from here is not clear how to get a contradiction.

Could someone help please?

Comment: $m$ is the Lebesgue measure ?

Comment: @P.Quinton yes.

Comment: This actually follows from the definition of Lebesgue measure. So, what' your definition of Lebesgue measurable ?  It's usually defined in the following way: A set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is called Lebesgue measurable if and only its inner measure equals its outer measure.

Answer (score 4):

This is a slog through a bit of set manipulations, and the definition of (outer measure):

Let $\epsilon>0.$ First suppose that $E$ is bounded. Then, there is a closed cube $Q$ such that

$\tag 1m(Q\cap E)=m(E).$

$\ Q\setminus E\ $ is measurable, so there is an open set $V\supseteq Q\setminus E$ such that

$\tag 2 m(V)<m(Q\setminus E)+\epsilon.$

Now, $Q\setminus V$ is compact, (it is closed and bounded), and since, from $(2)$, we have

$\tag3 m(Q\setminus E)>m(V)-\epsilon,$

we get

$\tag4 m(Q\setminus E)>m(V)-\epsilon\Rightarrow m(Q)>m(V)+m(Q\cap E)-\epsilon\Rightarrow m(Q\setminus V)>m(Q\cap E)-\epsilon.$

It now follows from $(4)$ and $(1)$ that

$\tag 6 m(Q\setminus V)>m(Q\cap E)-\epsilon=m(E)-\epsilon.$

Thus, $\tag 7 m(E\setminus (Q\setminus V))<\epsilon.$

If $E$ is not bounded, then we choose cubes $Q_i\subseteq Q_{i+1}$ increasing to $\mathbb R^n$ and apply the foregoing to $E_i= E\cap Q_i$ to find compact sets $K_i\subset E_i\subseteq E$ with the advertised property. Now choose $N$ so that

$\tag 8m(E) \le m(E_N ) + \epsilon/2.$

This is possible because $\bigcup E_i=E$ and $E_i\subseteq E_{i+1}$, so that $\lim m(E_i)=m(E).$ But we also have a compact set $K\subseteq E_N$ with

$\tag 9 m(E_N )\le  m(K) + \epsilon/2.$

This is possible since $E_N$ is bounded.

It now follows from $(8)$ and $(9)$ that

$\tag {10} m(E)\le m(K)+\epsilon,$

as desired.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask what is a closed cube? Is there a way to prove without $Q$, I haven't studied them yet.

Comment: I assume you are working in $\mathbb R^n$. A closed cube is just a set $[a_1,b_1]\times \cdots \times [a_n,b_n]$.You can use balls, or other closed compact sets to prove the claim.

Comment: oh ok, Why does $Q$ exist?

Comment: I added to the proof for clarification avoiding the issue by first assuming that $E$ is bounded and dealing with the unbounded cases after.

Comment: Why the bounded set $E$ implies the existence of $Q$ such that $m(E\cap Q)=E$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\mathrm{B}_n$ to be the closure of the ball $\mathrm{B}(0; n),$ which is compact. Observe that $\mathrm{E}_n = \mathrm{E} \cap \mathrm{B}_n$ converges to $\mathrm{E},$ hence its measure also converges. This shows $m(\mathrm{E}) = \lim_n m(\mathrm{E}_n)$ and since $\mathrm{E}_n \subset \mathrm{E},$ it turns out that $0 = \lim m(\mathrm{E} \setminus \mathrm{E}_n) = \lim m(\mathrm{E} \cap \mathrm{B}_n^\complement).$ Q.E.D.

Comment: How is $E_n$ defined? why can you say it's equal to $E\cap B_n$ ?

Comment: $\mathrm{E}_n$ is defined as the _intersection_ of (the set of common elements to both) $\mathrm{B}_n$ and $\mathrm{E}.$

Comment: I think you need to fix this argument because $E\cap B_n$ is not necessarily compact so truncating the sequence to get a complement of arbitrary small measure will not work here. You will need to get  open sets $V_n$  containing $E\cap B_n$ and work from there, which is basically my answer. I don't think you can get it any cheaper than my proof (the standard one). Happy to be proved wrong though!

Comment: Did you read my ammend?

Comment: I think you should have written: Define $E_n$ as $E_n=E\cap B_n$. Now I get what you meant.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I could have added a few words but it was clear in my head that the reader was capable of understanding that the $E_n$ were being defined as such for every natural $n.$

Answer (score 1):

The required claim easily follows from the regularity of the Lebesgue measure. For instance, by Proposition 6.2 from [here](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/real-an/3-06-leb-meas.pdf) if $n\ge 1$ is an integer, $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^n$, and $E$ be any Lebesgue measurable subset of $\Bbb R^n$ then $$m(E) = \sup\{m(K) : K\mbox{ is a compact subset of }\Bbb R^n\mbox{ with }K\subset E\}.$$

Now, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a compact subset $K$ of $E$ such that $m(K)>m(E)-\epsilon$. Since  $E=(E\cap K)\sqcup (E\cap K^c)=K\sqcup (E\cap K^c)$, we have 
$m(E)=m(K)+m(E\cap K^c)$, so $m(E\cap K^c)= m(E)-m(K)<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $E=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}E \cap [-n,n]$. Hence, by the continuity of measure, $m(E)=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}m(E \cap [-n,n])$. This implies that given an $\epsilon>0$ we can find a $n_{\epsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m(E)-m(E \cap [-n_{\epsilon}, n_{\epsilon}])<\epsilon$. By the additivity of measure the LHS equals $m(E\cap [-n_{\epsilon}, n_{\epsilon}]^C)$, so since $[-n_{\epsilon}, n_{\epsilon}]$ is compact we are done.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote on April.

Comment: @WillM. no it's not. The gist is the same though.

Comment: Considering the fact that the closure of the ball of radius $n$ in $\Bbb R$ is $[-n, n],$ this proof is literally the same as mine but with dimension $d = 1$ only.